# MySQL - Select N random rows of a different user where only value is contained less or equal toX

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select N random rows from a table, but in all of these rows a specific value may only occur X times.

Table "reviews":

```
*--------------------*
| ID | CODE_REVIEWER |
*--------------------*
| 1  |    2          |
| 1  |    3          |
| 1  |    4          |
*--------------------*
```

Table "users" (I left out a lot of unimportant stuff:

```
*----*
| ID |
*----*
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 5  |
*----*
```

Example output:
For X = 3:

```
*-----------*
| REVIEWER  |
*-----------*
|     4     |
|     1     |
|     5     |
*-----------*
```

For X = 2:

```
*-----------*
| REVIEWER  |
*-----------*
|     1     |
|     5     |
|     3     |
*-----------*
```

For X = 1 (empty):

```
*-----------*
| REVIEWER  |
*-----------*
```

So, it must be a ResultSet containing a few IDs that are different from the ID X, but these IDs may only occur in "table 2" as a "code_reviewer" N times.
***So everybody can be the "reviewer" FOR 3 people, and everbody can be reviewed BY 3 people***

Thanks!

**Edit:**
This is what I got so far:

```
select newid from (select id, count(*) as num from (select * from users
where id != ?) as users group by id order by RAND() LIMIT ?) as sb
where num < 3 and newid not in (select code_reviewer from reviews where id = ?)
```

It works perfectly, apart from that it sometimes returns for example

```
*---*
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
*---*
```

(Contains the 2 twice, which shouldn't be so)

Comment: Your expected results make no sense as per you provided sample input.

Comment: They do. For X = 3 and X = 2, the result contains 3 random IDs, and all of these IDs aren't reviewer for anybody else yet.
For X = 1:
The result is empty, because 1 is already "reviewed" 3 times (by 2, 3, 4)

Comment: @GurV just fixed one little flaw in the expected results

Comment: @DirtyDev If you think this makes sense, you must be high or something.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not xD
I think the last sentence tells you quite good what I want

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry but that isn't such an easy query

Comment: is the review considered completed if only there are 3 records? What if there are two records present for an id?

Comment: I think this is best handled in a stored procedure

Comment: What does 'X' represent in your example?

Comment: If there are 2 records, it still can be returned.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR X is the id of the person which will be reviewed, the return values are the "reviewers"

Comment: select newid from (select id, count(*) as num from (select * from users where id != ?) as users group by id order by RAND() LIMIT ?) as sb where num < 3 and newid not in (select code_reviewer from reviews where id = ?)

This is what I got so far, everything looks nice apart from that it still sometimes returns the same value twice

Comment: I'm starting to understand. Why do you expect the set to be empty when X = 1?

Comment: @GuillaumeCR not only if X = 1, but if there already are 3 reviewers for X

Comment: I understand, let me work on a solution. That's an interesting problem.

Comment: Do you expect to provide X as an input to a stored procedure, or do you want ALL the users to be paired up with 3 reviewers?

Comment: Thanks for helping me! I think you may just write 3 everywhere in the code as I could change it by myself later on.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I know MSSQL and not MySQL. I will try to answer using MSSQl, and hopefully that will lead you in the right direction.

I use variables to determine how many rows I should return, and then use a simple NEWID to act as a randomizer. (It is my understanding that you would order by RAND() in MySQL instead of NEWID())

```
declare @userId int
select @userId = 1
declare @existingReviewCount int
select @existingReviewCount = COUNT(*) from Reviews where Id = @userId
declare @requiredRowCount int
select @requiredRowCount = 3 - @existingReviewCount

select top (@requiredRowCount) Id from Users
where @userId != Id
order by NEWID()
```

Now replace @userId with 1 and it will return an empty set.

Comment: Thanks, but I have NO clue how to convert this to MySQL. I hope someone else can post some MySQL Code! But, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be essentially a top n per group problem.  There are a few ways to solve that.  Here is a quick and dirty way that will give you a comma separated list of id's that you need.  If you want to just explode these in your code you are good to go.

```
select u.*, 
    -- r_counts.cnt as reviews_count,
    substring_index(
        group_concat(u_rev.id order by rand()),
        ',',
        greatest(3-r_counts.cnt,0)) as reviewers
from users u
join users u_rev on u.id != u_rev.id
left join (
    select u.id, count(r.id) as cnt
    from users u
    left join reviews r on u.id = r.id
    group by u.id
) r_counts on r_counts.id = u.id
left join (
    select u.id, count(r.id) as cnt
    from users u
    left join reviews r on u.id = r.reviewer
    group by u.id, r.reviewer
) as did_review_counts
on did_review_counts.id = u_rev.id
where u.id = 11
and did_review_counts.cnt < 3
group by u.id;
```

If you need the results another way, google "top n per group mysql" and check out some of the solutions there.

**Note:** the 3 above would be your review number target. Edit:  Now this would need to be run only 1 at a time. Then rerun after each review was done.

Comment: Works almost flawless, but if the table is almost full, it only returns 2 reviewers, and not 3! I think that's because your code thinks: if A reviews B, then B reviews A, but that's not how it should work! More help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What I was doing was that if 3 reviews were required and 1 person had already reviewed the item it would return a random 2 reviewers.  Or if 2 had already reviewed, it would return 1 random reviewer.  What different were you looking for?

Comment: If person A is not "reviewed" by anybody, it sometimes returns only 2 persons as A's reviewers.

Comment: Can you describe the setup that generates that behavior?

Comment: Yep:
reviews (there are already 3 records generated by your script)

    (id, code_reviewer):
    10,3 |
    13,3 |
    12,3 |

users (IDs):

    10, 11, 12, 13, 3

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see that I missed the requirement that each person could only review 3 times, as well as be reviewed 3 times.  Let me see if there is a quick way to fix that.

Comment: I updated it in a bit of a rough way that works, but only if you are running it once for each user.  You can see I just put in a "less than 3" check.  It would be nice to have it work and give you all the results in 1 go, but if you want to run this 1 at a time I think it should work just fine.

Comment: Nope, not fully working. It still sometimes returns too few reviewers

Comment: I understood that if 1 person has already reviewed a user, that only 2 should be returned.  Is that not correct?

Comment: My program works so: The whole code you posted will only be run once (if the user X visits the page for the first time). In that case, I determine 3 persons the user X has to review. Vice verca, if another user Y visits the page for the first time, X could be selected by your function and could therefore be told to review Y.

Comment: So in total: Everyone has to review 3 random users and CAN BE reviewed BY another 3 random users

Comment: I see.  I was going from the target to be reviewed perspective.  How would that work for the first users?

Comment: There will be no "first user" as I'm going to manually insert at least 4 users into the database

Comment: I think it was working, then, in the first iteration of the query, but as you said it will not work when the table is almost full.  The first user who visits cannot review their own work, and so reviews no ones.  You would always have a problem when the table is almost full.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135789/discussion-between-dirtydev-and-alden-w).